# How to print n numbers including (n-1) special Characters in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a datatable which contains two columns InvoiceNo and InvoiceDate and i want to print those values in a text box like this:

```
Table
Invoice No        Invoice Date
001               2/10/2013
006               7/10/2014
009               9/11/2014
```

And i want to print this in a textbox like  Invoice Number 001,006,009  dated on   2/10/2013, 7/10/2014, 9/11/2014 repsectively. 
Now the problem is that how to insert ( , ) between them . and i am not able to do this.

Comment: can explain it more ? or what you have done so far ?

Comment: i was trying to make it through recursive loops but it was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't know anything about your work, here some steps that you might need;

- I assume you use Sql Server, use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to get these values.

---

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
```

- Use `SqlDataReader` to provide reading rows with `.Read` method (this reads your rows line by line) and define `string` variables as `finalNo` and `finalDate` to results of strings.

---

```
string finalNo = null, finalDate = null;
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(reader.Read())
   {

   }
}
```

- In your while loop, you can read your first column as `reader[0]` and second column as `reader[1]` and concatenate with `finalNo` and `finalDate` strings

---

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    finalNo += reader[0].ToString() + ",";    
    finalDate += reader[1].ToString() + " ,";    
}
```

- After that, you need to `TrimEnd()` the last comma on your strings like;

---

```
finalNo = finalNo.TrimEnd(',');
finalDate = finalDate.TrimEnd(',', ' ');
```

- Then you can use `string.Format` in it's `Text` property like;

---

```
TextBox1.Text = string.Format("Invoice Number {0} dated on {1}",
                              finalNo,
                              finalDate);
```

Comment: Gonul i was looking for voting up but it was not successful due to my less points but surely i marked it as a right answer !

Comment: @DeepakSetia No problem. You are right, voting up requires `15` reputation. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
    var result = string.Format("Invlice Number {0} dated on {1} resp.", String.Join(",", tables.Select(x => x.InvoiceNumber.ToString("000"))),
                                                                       String.Join(",", tables.Select(x => x.InvoiceDate.ToShortDateString())));
```

I have used List instead of dataTable for simplicity.

Or for DataTable, try this:-

```
string output = string.Format("Invoice Number {0} dated on {1} resp.", String.Join(",", (from DataRow dr in tab.Rows
                                                                                                 select ((int)dr["InvoiceNumber"]).ToString("000"))  ),
                                                                               String.Join(",", (from DataRow dr in tab.Rows
                                                                                                 select ((DateTime)dr["InvoiceDate"]).ToShortDateString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a mix of LINQ and String.Join().

```
var rows = (from DataRow row in table.Rows select row["columnname"].ToString()).ToList();
var commaSeparated = string.Join(", ", rows);
```